# What do the lists of numbers mean next to menu items in Prague?

Tags: food-and-drink, prague

I am currently in Prague, and I have noticed on quite a few menus there will be the following next to an item:

A: 1,3,7,8

The numbers may be different for each item, but it doesn't seem to mean anything. There's no choice of portion size, for example.

What does this mean?

Comment: Ingredients that one might be allergic to, with numbers further explained in the fineprint?

Comment: Check out this and see if it's what you're after http://blog.foreigners.cz/standardized-allergy-charts-in-prague/

Comment: @mts you can do it if you like :)

Comment: @GayotFow too kind of you but almost maxed out for today already :)

Comment: @mts, we'll leave it for a noob who wants to big up their presence here...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since 2015, restaurants in Czech Republic have to use standardized food allergy charts. Since the standardized allergens are numbered, restaurants often list just the numbers for each food, with a legend available (but the legend may be only in Czech).

This is based on EU regulation 1169/2011, which lists the allergens in [Annex II](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32011R1169#L_2011304EN.01004301):

> 1. Cereals containing gluten, namely: wheat, rye, barley, oats, spelt, kamut or their hybridised strains, and products thereof, except:
>
>    - wheat based glucose syrups including dextrose (1);
>    - wheat based maltodextrins (1);
>    - glucose syrups based on barley;
>    - cereals used for making alcoholic distillates including ethyl alcohol of agricultural origin;
> 2. Crustaceans and products thereof;
> 3. Eggs and products thereof;
> 4. Fish and products thereof, except:
>
>    - fish gelatine used as carrier for vitamin or carotenoid preparations;
>    - fish gelatine or Isinglass used as fining agent in beer and wine;
> 5. Peanuts and products thereof;
> 6. Soybeans and products thereof, except:
>
>    - fully refined soybean oil and fat (1);
>    - natural mixed tocopherols (E306), natural D-alpha tocopherol, natural D-alpha tocopherol acetate, and natural D-alpha tocopherol succinate from soybean sources;
>    - vegetable oils derived phytosterols and phytosterol esters from soybean sources;
>    - plant stanol ester produced from vegetable oil sterols from soybean sources;
> 7. Milk and products thereof (including lactose), except:
>
>    - whey used for making alcoholic distillates including ethyl alcohol of agricultural origin;
>    - lactitol;
> 8. Nuts, namely: almonds (Amygdalus communis L.), hazelnuts (Corylus avellana), walnuts (Juglans regia), cashews (Anacardium occidentale), pecan nuts (Carya illinoinensis (Wangenh.) K. Koch), Brazil nuts (Bertholletia excelsa), pistachio nuts (Pistacia vera), macadamia or Queensland nuts (Macadamia ternifolia), and products thereof, except for nuts used for making alcoholic distillates including ethyl alcohol of agricultural origin;
> 9. Celery and products thereof;
> 10. Mustard and products thereof;
> 11. Sesame seeds and products thereof;
> 12. Sulphur dioxide and sulphites at concentrations of more than 10 mg/kg or 10 mg/litre in terms of the total SO2 which are to be calculated for products as proposed ready for consumption or as reconstituted according to the instructions of the manufacturers;
> 13. Lupin and products thereof;
> 14. Molluscs and products thereof.
>
> (1)  And the products thereof, in so far as the process that they have undergone is not likely to increase the level of allergenicity assessed by the Authority for the relevant product from which they originated.

In your case, the meal contains #1 gluten, #3 eggs, #7 milk and #8 nuts.

Comment: The bad part is that some places _still_ leave those out, and I've even seen a place leaving out the obvious ones because "they're all fish, duh"

Comment: So is the "A" on the menu short for Allergy, or does it stand for something else like "Annex II"?

Comment: @MrLister I think it stands for "Allergens". I'm pretty sure "Annex II" is not how this list is known.

Comment: Since Czechia is a country of EU-haters, some restaurants decided to write a generic "all our food include all allergens" message to their menus instead of adding numbers.